# Order of a pole of $f(z) = \frac{e^z -1}{z^2(z-1)}$ at $1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand how I find the order of the pole at $\alpha = 1$,

$$f(z) = \frac{e^z -1}{z^2(z-1)}.$$

I thought it had an order of $1$ but the answer given is that it has an order of $2$. Can someone please explain how I get the right answer?

Comment: At $z=1$ the pole is indeed of order $1$ but ar $z=0$ the pole is of order $2$. Are you sure this is the answer ?

Comment: For me, your answer is correct, unless there's an error in the definition of the function.

Comment: Actually, even at z=0, it seems to be order 1, as $e^z-1\approx z$.

Comment: Indeed my comment was for the previous version with $e^2$ instead of $e^z$ (the last one making more sense ^^).